# I added a camera to the agent, but why can't I find the camera in the code?

Tags: anylogic

I added a camera to the agent, hoping to have the 3D view follow it as it starts to move. However, why can't I find the camera's attributes in the code?
[agent view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrMrY.png)
[logistics view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qABwR.png)

What I'm expecting is to have an `agent.personCamera`.

Comment: Likely, your camera is not inside a `DistributionWorker` agent type

Comment: Your expectations are correct - something else is the problem. Are you sure you placed the camera inside the 'DistributionWorker' agent? It is unclear from your screenshot